# Preview next and previous carousel item

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, carousel

Im trying to create a carousel where, apart of the active item, the user can preview part of the next and previous items. I made a draw to illustrate it:

[image]

I tried things like padding or margin, but anything works.

Here's a carousel to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/XpG8v/

```
        Ext.Viewport.add({
        xtype: 'carousel',
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        items: [{
            style: 'background-color: #00ffff;'
        },{
            style: 'background-color: #ff00ff;'
        },{
            style: 'background-color: #ffff00;'
        }]
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply set the 'itemLength' config to a fixed value, for example:

```
Ext.Viewport.add({
    xtype: 'carousel',
    itemLength: 200,
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Ups! I miss that, sorry. Thanks for your help!